# Roadmap for p-adic Hodge theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-hodge-theory, learning-roadmap

I'd like to be able to start studying p-adic Hodge theory and hope that by posing this question, I can be better prepared to work towards it. I ask for a roadmap because I understand that I have a lot to learn. It's pretty daunting. For background, I've only studied algebraic geometry and algebraic topology. I've also studied a little bit of elliptic curves and Galois representations. If I am to be more specific (because I understand that the theory has wide-ranging applications), I'm ultimately interested in the applications of the theory to Langlands (e.g. Fargues-Scholze's recent geometrization of local Langlands on the Fargues-Fontaine curve). Of course, this isn't to say that I'm not more broadly interested in many of the other algebro-geometric, topological, cohomological, and number theoretic aspects of the theory.

So, what prerequisites should I look to have before attempting to read something like Brinon and Conrad? What are good introductions to the subject once I have the prerequisites? How should I begin?

Thanks!

Comment: You could look at [Scholze's course](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Geometrization/), fixing the gaps along the way instead of learning them "bottom-up".

Comment: Dan Gulotta has given a [course](https://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/gulotta/tt20.html) on p-adic Hodge theory a couple years ago, and he did cover aspects of the Fargues-Fontaine curve that you seem to be interested in. You may want to take a look at his notes.

Comment: @Z.M My issue with doing such a thing is that I fear I'll get too sidetracked. Additionally, when I try to read even the first couple pages of an introductory course/set of notes on p-adic Hodge Theory, I get overwhelmed. This is part of my motivation for seeking a more organized approach.

Comment: @Wojowu A lot of good references in one place. I'll definitely save this one.

Comment: Brinon-Conrad is an excellent introduction to p-adic Hodge theory. There is also more "modern" lecture notes by [Serin Hong](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~serinh/). Perhaps you can try to read the book of Scholze-Weinstein after that.